# Как отсортировать элементы класса по возрастанию

Tags: c#, сортировка

```cs
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Road three = new Road { startPoint = "three", endPoint = "three", numRoad = 3 };
    Road one = new Road { startPoint = "one", endPoint = "one", numRoad = 1 };
    Road two = new Road { startPoint = "two", endPoint = "two", numRoad = 2 };
}

public class Road
{
    public String startPoint; 
    public String endPoint;
    public int numRoad;
}
```

Есть такой вот код, нужно вывести элементы класса Road отсортированные по полю numRoad по возрастанию. Не могу никак разобраться....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В C# (.NET) вы можете сортировать *массивы* и *списки*, так что вам надо поместить ваши элементы в массив или в список.
В обоих случаях либо полагаетесь на порядок сортировки по умолчанию, либо пишите свою функцию сравнения, так называемый *компаратор*.
Функция-компаратор получает два параметра и возвращает целое число.
Если число положительное, то первый элемент больше второго.
Если отрицательное, то второй элемент больше первого.
Если число равно нулю, элементы равны.
Пример такой функции для типа `Road`:

```
private static int RoadComparator(Road value1, Road value2)
{
    if (value1.numRoad > value2.numRoad)
        return 1;
    if (value1.numRoad < value2.numRoad)
        return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Вы можете его упростить, вызывая компаратор целых чисел для поля `numRoad`:

```
private static int RoadComparator(Road value1, Road value2)
{
    return value1.numRoad.CompareTo(value2.numRoad);
}
```

Компаратор можно реализовать как метод интерфейса `IComparable<T>`, но это, как говорят программисты, *бойлерплейт*, то есть многословное решение, которое мы вынуждены писать, потому что таковы ограничения языка или фреймворка.

Для класса `List<T>` компаратор можно записать как лямбда-функцию, это занимает гораздо меньше места.

```
List<Road> list = new List<Road>
{
    new Road { startPoint = "three", endPoint = "three", numRoad = 3 },
    new Road { startPoint = "one", endPoint = "one", numRoad = 1 },
    new Road { startPoint = "two", endPoint = "two", numRoad = 2 },
};
list.Sort((x, y) => x.numRoad.CompareTo(y.numRoad));
```

Answer (score 2):

Еще возможен вариант сортировки по вложенным полям класса через Linq

```
List<Road> roads = new List<Road>
{
    new Road { startPoint = "three", endPoint = "three", numRoad = 3 },
    new Road { startPoint = "one", endPoint = "one", numRoad = 1 },
    new Road { startPoint = "two", endPoint = "two", numRoad = 2 },
};
var sortedRoads = roads.OrderBy(r => r.numRoad).ToList();
```

[Пример полного кода](https://dotnetfiddle.net/s40ZEo)